# How can i return List from Class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            mylist myitems1 = new mylist("Yusuf","Karatoprak");
            SelectedItemsList slist = new SelectedItemsList();
            slist.Items.Add(myitems1);
            foreach( object o in slist.Items)
            Console.Write(o.ToString()+"\n");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

```
    public class mylist
    {
        private string Ad;
        private string SoyAd;
        public mylist(string ad, string soyad)
        {
            Ad = ad;
            SoyAd = soyad;
        }
```

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Ad:" + this.Ad;
        }
    }
    public class SelectedItemsList
    {
        public List Items;
```

public SelectedItemsList()
    {
        Items = new List<mylist>();

    }
}</code></pre>

i want to return an arraylist or list form mylist class but how? return this.Ad, also retun this.SoayAd etch.
Please look ToString() procedure: it is return Ad but i want to return Ad also SoyAd together. Not only Ad ,but also Ad,SoyAd in a List.

Comment: You have some misprint in HTML tags

Comment: Dude, stop messing around with markup. Rephrase the question.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is very unclear, but if you mean you want mylist to have a method which returns a list containing Ad and SoyAd, then just do it like this:

```
// This could be a property
public IList<string> GetAds()
{
    List<string> ret = new List<string>();
    ret.Add(Ad);
    ret.Add(SoyAd);
    return ret;
}
```

If you can make do with `IEnumerable<string>` you could use an iterator block:

```
// This could be a property
public IEnumerable<string> GetAds()
{
    yield return Ad;
    yield return SoyAd;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To return an ArrayList or List, just use "public List someFunction()" or "public ArrayList someFunction()".
If this is not what you want, please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

To return list only of `ad` or `soyad` keep it independent lists, filled on adding